# Residue Classes

Tags: prime-numbers

I am trying to show that:

$$\sum\limits_{\beta \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*}{\beta^{-1}}=\sum\limits_{\beta \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*}{\beta}=0$$

Where p is an odd prime.

I really dont know where to start, but my best guess is that because B and the inverse of B should cancel out, then it should equal 0. Am I right in thinking that?

How would I go about proving this equation, I was thinking of using the additive inverse theorem.

Thanks

Comment: What's "the aditive inverse theorem"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following sets are identical:

$$\{x\in\Bbb Z_p^*\}=\{x^{-1}\;;\;x\in\Bbb Z_p^*\}$$

thus both sums in your link are identical. Finally

$$\sum_{x\in\Bbb Z_p^*}x=1+2+...+(p-1)=\frac{p(p-1)}2=0\pmod p$$

since $\,p\,$ is prime.

Comment: "since $p$ is prime" --- indeed, since $p$ is odd.